# Does the $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt[n]{4}-1)^{\ln(n)}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

To check for the convergence, I used most of the common tests like, Ratio test, Root test, Divergence test, integral test and also tried to use a comparison. But none of them gave a satisfactory result.

Appreciate your help of this

Answer (score 1):

$4^{1/n}$ is approximately $1 + c/n$ (where $c = \log 4,$ but it is irrelevant.

So, the term is approximately $\frac{1}{n^{\log n}},$ which goes to $0$ faster than any power of $n.$ By the comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$ the series converges.